# Scala jar: Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to run a jar for a Scala application (created using `sbt clean compile package`) as follows:

```
java -cp /scala-hello-world.jar:/scala-library-2.12.2.jar HelloWorld
```

Here is the directory structure:

```
.
├── HelloWorld.class
├── HelloWorld$.class
├── scala-hello-world.jar
└── scala-library-2.12.2.jar
```

But when I try to execute it, I receive the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
```

At first, I thought it was because my directory was missing the class files, but since I've added them back in, I still receive the same error.  I've also tried:

```
java -cp . HelloWorld
```

Any ideas?

These are the contents of HelloWorld.scala:

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your HelloWorld contain? Does it have any package information?

Comment: How is `scala-hello-world.jar` created? Do you run `sbt package`?

Comment: @ShivamPuri, I edited my original post.  HelloWorld.scala is under `src/main/scala`.

Comment: @MarioGalic edited.. yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your classpath has a bug. If you are in the current directory which has

```
.
├── scala-hello-world.jar
└── scala-library-2.12.2.jar
```

then the try executing with

```
java -cp scala-library-2.12.2.jar:scala-hello-world.jar HelloWorld
```

instead of

```
java -cp /scala-library-2.12.2.jar:/scala-hello-world.jar HelloWorld
```